# Extract XML sqlQuery Issues in R - Querying Clob Column

Tags: sql, r, xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have a oracle DB table called CRS.CRS_FILES, with a column called FILE_DATA -inside that CLOB column is a large XML string.

```
FILE_DATA   FILE_CREATION_DATE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT   1/1/2020
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT   1/5/2020
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT   1/6/2019
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT   1/1/2020
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><REPORT   1/5/2020
```

Here is the first few lines of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<REPORT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201">
<CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>2020-10-08T06:49:31.813812</CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>-
<AGENCYIDENTIFIER>MILWAUKEE</AGENCYIDENTIFIER>-
<AGENCYNAME>Milwaukee Police Department</AGENCYNAME>
```

it is set up with the following Xpath I want to query:

```
//REPORT/AGENCYIDENTIFIER

query_string2 <- "SELECT
XMLTYPE(t.FILE_DATA).EXTRACT('//REPORT/AGENCYNAME/text()').getClobVal()
FROM CRS.CRS_FILES t"
idtable <- sqlQuery(ch,query_string2, max=10)

query_string2 <- "SELECT
XMLTYPE(t.FILE_DATA).EXTRACT('//REPORT/AGENCYNAME/text()').getStringVal()
FROM CRS.CRS_FILES t"
idtable <- sqlQuery(ch,query_string2, max=10)
```

I am not sure what I am doing - I know that sqlQuery when passing SQL queries there are some minor format issues, but no matter what I try, my result looks like the following:

```
XMLTYPE(T.FILE_DATA).EXTRACT('//REPORT/AGENCYNAME/TEXT()').GETCLOBVAL()
1   NA
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA
6   NA
7   NA
8   NA
9   NA
10  NA
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to extract the value Milwaukee Police Department (see below) (of course I would rename col to something like AGENCYNAME)

```
XMLTYPE(T.FILE_DATA).EXTRACT('//REPORT/AGENCYNAME/TEXT()').GETCLOBVAL()
1   Milwaukee Police Department
2   Milwaukee Police Department
3   Milwaukee Police Department
4   Milwaukee Police Department
5   Milwaukee Police Department
6   Milwaukee Police Department
7   Milwaukee Police Department
8   Milwaukee Police Department
9   Milwaukee Police Department
10  Milwaukee Police Department
```

Comment: Please also add an example of what you expect to get - would be helpful.

Comment: So both `getStringVal()` AND `getClobVal()` result in `NA` for all rows?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Not working for me in R, what does X and i denote? I am getting "string literal expected" error, this looks promising!!

Comment: @user13203033 What is not working? You don't appear to have an `X` in your question and the `i` is one of your XML namespaces (so you'll need to tell us why you are using it). Was this meant to be a comment on an answer rather than on your question?

Comment: I see now regarding the i, i paste the query as you wrote it into R as a sqlQuery and it is returning an error. Is there a specific formatting for R SqlQuery?

Comment: If you want to put an SQL query into a string in R then just escape the quotes that need escaping. So if your query string starts and ends with double quotes then everywhere where there is a double quote in the SQL statement you will need to escape that quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`EXTRACT(xml)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-XML.html#GUID-593295AA-4F46-4D75-B8DC-E7BCEDB1D4D7) is deprecated. Instead, use `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT x.agencyname
FROM   CRS.CRS_FILES c
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES(
           'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "i",
           DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201'
         ),
         '/REPORT'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( c.file_data )
         COLUMNS
           crsreporttimestamp TIMESTAMP     PATH 'CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP',
           agencyidentifier   VARCHAR2(50)  PATH 'AGENCYIDENTIFIER',
           agencyname         VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'AGENCYNAME'
       ) x
```

or, in R it should be the same with the double quotes escaped:

```
query_string2 <- "SELECT x.agencyname
FROM   CRS.CRS_FILES c
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES(
           'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS \"i\",
           DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201'
         ),
         '/REPORT'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( c.file_data )
         COLUMNS
           crsreporttimestamp TIMESTAMP     PATH 'CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP',
           agencyidentifier   VARCHAR2(50)  PATH 'AGENCYIDENTIFIER',
           agencyname         VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'AGENCYNAME'
       ) x"

idtable <- sqlQuery(ch,query_string2, max=10)
```

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CRS.CRS_FILES ( FILE_DATA CLOB );

INSERT INTO CRS.crs_files VALUES (
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<REPORT xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201">
  <CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>2020-10-08T06:49:31.813812</CRSREPORTTIMESTAMP>-
  <AGENCYIDENTIFIER>MILWAUKEE</AGENCYIDENTIFIER>-
  <AGENCYNAME>Milwaukee Police Department</AGENCYNAME>
</REPORT>'
)
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | AGENCYNAME                  |
> | :-------------------------- |
> | Milwaukee Police Department |
> ```

---

If you do want to use `EXTRACT` then you need to specify the XML namespace:

```sql
SELECT XMLTYPE(t.FILE_DATA).EXTRACT(
         '//REPORT/AGENCYNAME/text()',
         'xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201"'
       ).getStringVal() AS agencyname
FROM   CRS.CRS_FILES t
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | AGENCYNAME                  |
> | :-------------------------- |
> | Milwaukee Police Department |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c9e1ca6abcecd9db5b51e295be66656)*

Comment: The columns section at the bottom of the XMLTABLE query, do they have to be in order ? I tried to change the vars to other ones in the XML string and its throwing errors

Comment: I guess because the /REPORT part right I can only ref ones in that section? So if I had a var located at /REPORT/APPROVED/SEED I would need to change PATH under columns to /APPROVED/SEED?

Comment: @user13203033 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f40ebd708030a4a9f4c230407d64997)

Comment: Thank you for all your help MT0. One last question, what if I have multiple /REPORT/APPROVED/SEED values for each AGENCYNAME? Is there a way where the query can output duplicate AGENCYNAME but the table is unique on SEED?

Answer (score 1):

Current Oracle query is the issue and not `RODBC::sqlQuery` method. Simply, your XPath is not accounting for the default namespace in root node. However, the XMLType [**`extract()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm#i1030920) function allows you to define a temporary prefix in order to use in XPath:

```sql
extract(XMLType_instance IN XMLType, 
        XPath_string IN VARCHAR2, 
        namespace_string In VARCHAR2 := NULL) RETURN XMLType;
```

Therefore, once a prefix is defined like `doc` apply it to XPath:

```r
query_string2 <- "SELECT XMLTYPE(t.FILE_DATA).EXTRACT('//doc:REPORT/doc:AGENCYNAME/text()',
                           'xmlns:doc=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CrashReport.DataLayer.v20170201\"').getStringVal()
                  FROM CRS.CRS_FILES t"

idtable <- sqlQuery(ch,query_string2, max=10)
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/DVDC79947)</kbd> *(works for `getClobVal` and `getStringVal`)*

Comment: HOLY CRAP FINALLY IT WORKED!!!!!!!!! You are a great help!!!!

Comment: How would I select multiple items? Like say if I wanted AGENCYNAME twice, where would i put it?

Comment: Simply add to the `SELECT` clause for other XPath calls. BTW - be sure to heed [@MTO's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64360428/1422451) which albeit is longer is preferred since apparently `EXTRACT` is deprecated. I am no Oracle expert to know that.